# Linux terminal Alt+Arrow word delimiter

Tags: xterm, lxterminal

In an SSH session or local terminal session (xterm), using Alt+left or right arrow allows me to skip forward and backward one *word*. In the example below, when using Alt+left arrow, the cursor stops on, from the end of the command, 'p', 'R', 'F', '2', '2', '2', '4', '1', '1', '1', '1', 'f', 'p', 'R', '1', '2', '0', 'F', 'T', 'f', 'f', 'u', and 'c'. This leads me to believe the delimiters would be "._/:{}- ", among others. Can I get rid of some of these delimiters? /etc/inputrc doesn't seem to define the delimiters from what I can ascertain.

```
curl -u ftpuser:ftppass -T{File1_04-20-16_Rev1.pdf} ftp://192.168.10.100/4_20_2016/20160420_File1_Rev1.pdf
```